# How to inherit and modify "Name" in Sale Order lines - Odoo14

Tags: python, overriding, odoo

My goal is to make the "Description" (`name`) field located in `sale.order.line` in order to show the products "Sales Description"(`description_sale`)....and NOT the products "Name"+"Sales Description" as per default.

I've seen someone said i have to override the function `product_id_change` but i don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def product_id_change(self):
    res = super(classname, self).product_id_change()
    self.name = self.product_id.description_sale if self.product_id and self.product_id.description_sale else self.product_id.name
    return res
```

Comment: This is simpler than I thought, I had indeed a problem with my super() because I called an unnecessary parameter. Thanks for the help, it works !